# document getElementById returns null in ng-repeated dom elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I have ng-repeat loop with canvas items:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in todos">
        <canvas id="canvas-{{item.Guid}}"></canvas>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Somewhere in code, there is function addTodo, which is somehow like:

```
            $scope.todos.push(newTodo); 
            $scope.renderPDF(newTodo.Attachment,cxId);
```

Where cxId is canvas id and renderPDF renders something on canvas using getElementById. 
But when I add todo, although in **Chrome Developer Console** there is canvas with correct id, I get error that getElementById on cxId returns **null**. 
All is done correctly and Angular uses two-way data binding, so why there is a problem?

Comment: When are you running `.getElementById`? Is it before or after the elements are compiled by ngRepeat?

Comment: I use it after adding element to array. There is moment between adding to array and after i use getElementById. But i think i call getElementById before digest cycle ends, so compilation by ng-repeat..

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to explain, since it's peculiar. 
Angular uses Two way data-binding, but in ng-book i read about this process. 
And all parameters that are in view ( in this case, also todos which generate canvas-id ), all these parameters which are in scope are set watch on them. On their change, there goes change to a view. This process is two-way data binding. It happens in digest cycle. So there is a time to do this and when i am pushing todo to array it's not started this digest cycle yet. 
Solution is to enforce digest cycle after adding element to array, what will listen to changes in scope variables:

Instead of:

```
$scope.todos.push(newTodo);    
$scope.renderPDF(newTodo.Attachment,cxId);
```

There should be:

```
$scope.todos.push(newTodo);    
$scope.apply();
$scope.renderPDF(newTodo.Attachment,cxId);
```

apply method enforces digest cycle.

Comment: But i have message  $apply already in progress, but no null from getElementById anymore. Am i right?

Comment: please use edit button to extend your question instead of posting an answer

Comment: Why? There is an option answer your own question, during posting a question, why not to use it?